# Python Random Playing Card Generator Game

Tags: python

I'm currently attempting to create a program in Python that will allow a random card to be created using the random function, with a suit and the card number. 
 The code so far is shown below...

```
import random
num1 = random.randint(1,13)
num2 = random.randint(1,4)
cardnum1 = ""
cardnum2 = ""

input ("Press the enter key to continue \n")



if True:
    if num1 == 11:
        cardnum1 = "Queen"
    elif num1 == 12:
        cardnum1 = "Jack"
    elif num1 == 13:
        cardnum1 = "King"
    elif num1 < 10:
        cardnum1 = num1
    elif num2 == 1:
        cardnum2 = "Spades"
    elif num2 == 2:
        cardnum2 = "Hearts"
    elif num2 == 3:
        cardnum2 = "Diamonds"
    elif num2 == 4:
        cardnum2 = "Clubs"

print (cardnum1, cardnum2)
```

If the card number (num1) is 11, 12 or 13, the card will be Jack, Queen and King respectively. If the variable num22 is equal to 1, 2, 3 or 4, the card will be Spades, Hearts, Diamonds and Clubs respectively too. 
The issue I have here is that rather than having both the card number and its suit printed together, the IDLE only prints the card number and chooses not to print the variable cardnum2. For example, if num1 is 8 and num2 is Diamonds, I would expect the IDLE to print "9 Diamonds" but instead prints only "9". I can only choose this method to solving and writing the program, so can someone please help clear the code and help me with this code?

 
 Thanks, Jack.

UPDATE: Can I just ask, how can I loop the program so that it repeatedly creates new cards when the user presses the enter key?

Comment: Why do you have the condition `if True:`?

Comment: @jabaldonedo I have tried other conditions and they have somehow messed up the code. This seems to be the easiest condition of the lot. Just to ask, what would you recommend?

Comment: Your condition is redundant, you don't need it, you will always enter in that block of code

Comment: @JackDavis: Get rid of the `if True:` line and unindent the block below it.

Comment: @jabaldonedo oh ok. I didn't know that. Thank you very much nonetheless!

Comment: maybe define a constant `SUITS = [None, 'Spades', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs']`  Then instead of the second part of the if you can just `cardnum2 = SUITS[num2]`

Comment: `elif num1 < 10` should be `elif num1 <= 10` as 10 is a valid value for a card

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your big `if: elif:` block:

```
elif num1 < 10:
    cardnum1 = num1
elif num2 == 1:
    cardnum2 = "Spades"
```

You want to deal with `num2` separately to `num1`, so that should be:

```
elif num1 < 10:
    cardnum1 = num1

if num2 == 1:
    cardnum2 = "Spades"
```

or, *much* simpler, use a pair of dictionaries, the idiomatic replacement for a whole bunch of `elif`s:

```
faces = {11: "Queen", 12: "Jack", 13: "King"} # it's usually J Q K, though
cardnum1 = faces.get(num1, num1)
suits = {1: "Spades", 2: "Hearts", 3: "Diamonds", 4: "Clubs"}
cardnum2 = suits[num2]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import random


cards = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"] 
suits = ["Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs"]

print(random.choice(cards) + " of " + random.choice(suits))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that after performing the checks for `num1` you continue to use `elif` for all of your checks with `num2`.  This means that you will only ever enter one of the first four code blocks.  Instead, start a new `if` statement for the `num2` checks:

```
if num1 == 11:
    cardnum1 = "Queen"
elif num1 == 12:
    cardnum1 = "Jack"
elif num1 == 13:
    cardnum1 = "King"
elif num1 < 10:
    cardnum1 = num1

if num2 == 1:
    cardnum2 = "Spades"
elif num2 == 2:
    cardnum2 = "Hearts"
elif num2 == 3:
    cardnum2 = "Diamonds"
elif num2 == 4:
    cardnum2 = "Clubs"
```

Also, using `if True:` is pretty pointless since that code will always end up running.

Answer (score 1):

This code might look a bit *ugly* because I removed a-lot of variables and stuck them in the input() but it's compact.

```
from random import randint,choice
def main():
    suits = ["Spades","Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs"]

    user_input = input(str(randint(1,13)) + " of " + str(choice(suits)) + ". To run again press [ENTER] key.")
    main() if user_input == "" else exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
elif num1 < 10:
    cardnum1 = num1
elif num2 == 1:
    cardnum2 = "Spades"
```

Try:

```
else:
    cardnum1 = num1
if num2 == 1:
    cardnum2 = "Spades"
```

Because you are using `elif` for logic concerning both `num1` and `num2`, only one or the other is being set.  You need two separate `if` tests.

As you continue to learn you will find other things in your code that can be made simpler, as other answers point out.

Answer (score 0):

@TwilightKillerX has given a really nice and compact answer to Jack's last bit of the question. The recursive part of function `main()` calling itself might not be that straight forward for Jack to understand. Here is an iterative implementation that Jack might appreciate using a `while` loop and Python 3.6.9

```
__author__ = "TwilightKillerX"

from random import randint, choice

def jack_chooses_a_card(suits: dict):
    """
    Please put a doc string here
    """
    print(str(randint(1,13)) + " of " + str(choice(suits)))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"]

    print("Just press [ENTER] to get started")
    user_input = input("")

    while user_input == "":
        jack_chooses_a_card(suits)
        user_input = input("\nTo run again press [ENTER] key, entering anything else would terminate the program\n")
```